# ionic data randomly don't display

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm devloping an aplication on ionic using api when I go on a certain view the first time some data sometimes don't display. however the data seem to have no problem to load.

here a screenshot of my problem :
[image]

controller.js :

```
.controller('activite', function($http,$state,settings,$scope,$rootScope,ActiFactory,EventFactory)
{
  console.log('ActiFactory',ActiFactory);
  evenement_selectionne=ActiFactory.evenement_selectionne;
  $scope.evenement_selectionne=evenement_selectionne;

  activite_selectionne=ActiFactory.activite_selectionne;
  $scope.activite_selectionne=activite_selectionne;
}
```

activite.html :

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title> 
    {{activite_selectionne.nom_activite}}
  </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">
          {{evenement_selectionne.lieu}}, {{evenement_selectionne.date}}. {{activite_selectionne.heure_activite}}.
        </span>
      </label>
    </form>
    <div>
      {{activite_selectionne.description}}
    </div>
    <div>
    nombre d'inscrits : {{activite_selectionne.inscris.length}}/{{activite_selectionne.limit_particip_activ}}
    </div>
    <button style="color:#FFFFFF;" ng-click="inscription()" class="button button-balanced  button-block icon-right ion-arrow-right-c">
      S'inscrire à cet évenement !
    </button>
      <img src="{{activite_selectionne.image}}" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: show html code also

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal done :)